# Find points where the plane $6x+y+9z=54$ intersects each coordinate axis.

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

For this I need to find points $(a,b,c)$ for the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and $z$-axis.

I know how to solve this when given two planes. First I'd set $x=0$ and have $y+9z=54$, but with only one plane I don't know how to get a $y$ or $z$ value.

Answer (score 4):

Set two of the variables to $0$ and solve for the remaining one. For example,

$$x=y=0\implies 6x+y+9z=9z=54\implies z=6$$

so the $z$-intercept is the point $(0,0,6)$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, the equation of given plane: $6x+y+9z=54$ can be easily written in **intercept form** as follows
$$\frac{6x}{54}+\frac{y}{54}+\frac{9z}{54}=1\iff \frac{x}{9}+\frac{y}{54}+\frac{z}{6}=1$$
$9, 54$ & $6$ are $x, y$ & $z$ intercepts respectively hence the points of intersection of plane with the coordinate axes $x$, $y$ & $z$ respectively are $(9,0,0)$, $(0,54,0)$ & $(0,0,6)$

Answer (score 1):

Set $x$ and $y$ equal to zero and solve for $z$ :  $(0,0,6)$

Set $x$ and $z$ equal to zero and solve for $y$ :  $(0,54,0)$

Set $y$ and $z$ equal to zero and solve for $x$ :  $(9,0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try setting each axis variable $x,y,z$ to $0$. From this you get 
$y+9z = 54$,
$6x+y=54$ and $6x+9z=54$. Then you have three equations with 3 unknowns so you should be able to solve for them (using substitution for example).
I guess I did not understand the authors question.

Comment: this is wrong  ( $z = 3$ with your solution )

Comment: @Tortar can you please tell me how you calculated that. By setting one the variables $x,y,z=0$ should yield the correct solution.

Comment: @Tortar I am not sure how you are solving that in wolfram, but that is definitely incorrect. This can clearly be see by letting $z=0$ for example. The resulting equation becomes $6x+y=54$ which has many solutions, i.e $x=9,y=0$.

Comment: Ahh sorry , maybe I misunderstood your solution...I thought you intended something else , my mistake

Comment: @Tortar no worries, I guess I misunderstood the question as it seems the author is interested when the function intersects with the plane not just an axis.

Comment: exactly , and I misunderstood your answer , a set of misunderstandings ahah

Comment: @Tortar haha yes, not sure why I got a -1 reputation but oh well

Comment: If you edit (otherwise I can't) , I change my downvote because it's not fair

Comment: @Tortar thanks, I just edited the post

Comment: "it results in x=9/2,y=27,z=3" That doesn't make any sense that point isn't on *ANY* of the axis.  You are answering a question that isn't being asked.

Comment: You answered the following question: If we take the three $xy,xz,yz$ planes, took the three lines where this plane intersected those planes, extended those three lines into three new planes containing the lines and perpendiculare to each $xy,xz,yz$ plane and what point do these three planes intersect?

Comment: Not so bad after all ( I can ensure you that It was my intent :D)

Answer (score 0):

A plane will intersect an axis when that axis value is something be the *other* axes are *all* zero.

So it intersects the $x$ axis when $y=z =0$.

And it intersects the $y$ axis when $x=z=0$.

And it intersects the $z$ axis whte $x = y = 0$.

So the solutions should be easy to find.

$6x + y + 9z = 54; y=0; z=0$ means $6x + 0 + 9*0 = 54$ means $x=9$ has solution at $(x,y,z) = (6,0,0)$.

$6x + y + 9z=54; x=0;z=0$  means  $y=54$ has solution at $(x,y,z) = (0,54,0)$

And $6x + y+9z =54; x=0;y=0$ means $9z=54$ means $z=6$ has solution at $(x,y,z) = (0,0,6)$.

---

I think you might be confusing when does the plane intersect the three $xy$, $xz$ and $yz$ *planes*.  When two *planes* intersect they intersect at a line with infinite points (as opposed to a plane and a *line* which intersect at a point).

In this case the plane will intersect the $xy$ plane at the line $6x + y + 9*0 = 6x+y = 54$.  The plane will intersect the $xz$ plane at the line $6x + 9z = 54$ and will intersect eh $yz$ plane at the line $y+9z = 54$.
$6*0 + y + 9*0 = 54$